# How to send function pointers from VFP to C language dll

Tags: c, dll, function-pointers, visual-foxpro

Say I have a function in C language dll as show below

```
EXTERN_C void WINAPI LoadCallbackInt(PCALLBACKINTFUNC func);
```

with the function pointer being defined as the following

```
typedef void (WINAPI *PCALLBACKINTFUNC)(int value);
```

How do call the function and send the `PCALLBACKINTFUNC` parameters when VFP? Or else, is there other methods to implement events in dll that is used with VFP (assuming that I am not allowed to use COM of OCX for this problem)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain that the DECLARE syntax in VFP does not support function parameters like this. It would potentially be possible if you wrote an FLL(C/C++ Library usable in VFP) that handles the raw API calls above. I'm not sure if there's a way for an FLL to call a VFP function, but you can definitely have a timer in VFP poll the FLL to see if the callback has been called...

Not a great solution, but VFP was never designed for this, and getting it to work with things like this generally requires rather hacky solutions-- if it's possible at all.